Power Platform - new connector added in sensitive evironment
I was given a task to monitor some robots in power platform, i added all the power platform connectors, opened a rule template for the new connector added. inc are going in the siem queue but there are some thigns i cannot get- the name of the connector id all i get is the shared-uiflow-... but none of the devs can connect the id to the name of the conncetor, is there a way i can do it?
and another side questions - what activity ca cause "PutConnection" events besides adding a new connector?
Thanks for any help !
Ive tried looking in different tables for the connector name so i can match it with its id but no success

The connector ID is a unique identifier assigned to each connector in Power Platform. It is not the same as the connector name
